# I have a progress bar that displays on my emulator but not real device

Tags: android

I have a custom loading bar in my app, when used in my emulator the loading bar is displayed along with the text as defined in the layout with no problems, but when i run the app on my device the loading bar box comes up but it does not display the loading icon or the loading text, just a blank space.

Below is my custom bar class

```
 public class csBar
    {
        public static csBar s_m_oCShowProgress;
        public static Context m_Context;
        public static Dialog m_Dialog;

        public csBar(Context m_Context) {
            this.m_Context = m_Context;
        }

        public static csBar getInstance() {
            if (s_m_oCShowProgress == null) {
                s_m_oCShowProgress = new csBar(m_Context);
            }
            return s_m_oCShowProgress;
        }

        public void showProgress(Context m_Context)
        {
            m_Dialog = new Dialog(m_Context);
            m_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
            m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_bar);
            m_Dialog.setTitle("Loading ....");
            m_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            m_Dialog.setCancelable(true);
            m_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            m_Dialog.show();
        }

        public static void hideProgress() {
            if (m_Dialog != null) {
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                m_Dialog = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my layout for it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large">
    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What the Android's version of the emulator and the phone?

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo version 22 and my phone is 23

Comment: What's your phone? Be more detailed.